# TeamViewer Free Edition 1 minute limit

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I have used TeamViewer to connect with my second computer and do some stuff on it from my main machine. I have never had any problems with connection limits etc. I use this software just at the home.

Unfortunately, yesterday I tried to connect with a second computer and do some things there, but TeamViewer close my connection after 1 minute of streaming. I repeated this a few times, but the result was always the same.

What is going on? As I remember, the free version for home usage has never had some limitations. So this 1 min limit is some kind of bug, or did they change their policy for the very restricted model?

On a machine that should be the host of remote desktop I have installed Windows 10 Home Edition, so I can't use native Windows RDP app.

Comment: *What is going on?* Ask Teamviewer and not random people on the internet.

Comment: TeamViewer has taken a lot more strict stance on how the app is used. You might fare better with an alternative remote access solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your connection is being limited because [TeamViewer suspects that you are using it for commercial purposes](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/kb/articles/5265-why-do-i-see-commercial-use-suspected-commercial-use-detected). If you believe that it is incorrect (which appears to be common), then you can use [this form](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/reset-management/) to request that they investigate.

Worth noting that there is no guarantee that they will unblock your ID. If they don't then you will either need to pay for a licence or find alternative software.

Comment: Wow, thanks - I didn't suspect that my scope of using TV could be admitted as commercial usage. Well, I'll write to their support and will explain the situation. Thanks for that tip!

Comment: They've flagged my account twice despite the fact that I only use it about once a month to connect to my parents laptop to fix a problem. In fairness though, they did remove the restriction in less than 24 hours.

Comment: After some time I finally received mail from TeamViewer support. They have agreed with me that I do not use TeamViewer commercially and unlocked my ID, so thank you for this solution.